# apache spark saveAsObjectFile writes to hdfs by default

Tags: hdfs, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

- When I am running spark locally(non hdfs), RDD saveAsObjectFile writes the file to local file system (ex : path /data/temp.txt)
- when I am running spark on YARN cluster,  RDD saveAsObjectFile writes the file to hdfs. (ex : path /data/temp.txt )

Is there a way to explictly mention local file system instead of hdfs when running spark on YARN cluster.

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly specify "file:///" prefix in the argument.

```
yourRDD. saveAsObjectFile("file:///path/to/local/filesystem")
```